# BlackBerry PlayBook debugging issue

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I have compiled my application and when I tried to debug it gave me following errors, can someone help how could I resolve this error

Error in final launch sequence
Cannot prepare and download the binary
Packaging failed:1
Error: Unable to resolve path variable "workspace_loc" and here is the stack trace of exception

```
at com.qnx.tools.ide.bbt.debug.core.internal.launch.BBTLaunchUtils.prepareAndDownloadBinaries(BBTLaunchUtils.java:305)
at com.qnx.tools.ide.bbt.debug.ui.internal.launch.BBTDSFFinalLaunchSequence.stepPrepareAndDownloadBinariesRemote(BBTDSFFinalLaunchSequence.java:93)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.ReflectionSequence$ReflectionStep.execute(ReflectionSequence.java:155)
at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.Sequence.executeStep(Sequence.java:452)
at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.Sequence.access$2(Sequence.java:366)
at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.Sequence$2.handleSuccess(Sequence.java:413)
at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.RequestMonitor.handleCompleted(RequestMonitor.java:353)
at org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.concurrent.RequestMonitor$2.run(RequestMonitor.java:298)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Regards
Ahsan

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your project in Flash Builder and then **Resource -> Linked Resources -> Path Variables**: do you have a **WORKSPACE_LOC** variable there and does it point to a valid and writtable path?